# Can I add Committers List/Email List to the Content of the Email-ext Plugins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I need to get the committers list when the build is failed,Can I add committers List or committers' email list to the Content of the Email-ext Plugins?is there a env like ${COMMITTERS}?

Answer (score 1):

@Tracy - Jenkins does not expose the committers information as environment variables. Neither does Email-Ext Plugin. But the [Email extension plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) lets you create your own email format by using your own jelly script. Take a look at [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/3604514/txt.jpg) and [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/3604514/html.jpg) To see how to configure this type of email format, go the the email extension plugin page and search for 'Jelly content'. This should take you to that section. Try this out and let me know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the comitter Name by using `${CHANGES,  format="%a"}` But I am not sure if you can show multiple different names if there is more than one comitter